# Is it ok to use SESSION vars on the get page?

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to embed some ajax in my project. 
What happens is that I am using a get method to access some other php page, with some parameters, where the page I get, needs to go to the DB and bring some data. But I need that data according to that specific user.

Since the page that actually calls the get page already set up session variables (user ID to be precise), I am using the same session variables now. So, is that ok to use that same session to verify the user identity on the get page ? or is there another way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's absolutely fine and in fact how you're supposed to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Using session variables is OK, however you have to take care of session timeouts. It may happen that the user still has the page open, when the session expires. In this moment, your AJAX request will fail, as the `$_SESSION` would be empty. Hence, you have to take care when you process the results of your ajax call.